# SmtpClient и Port для иностранной рассылки

Tags: c#, smtp, port

Какие Smtp и порты можно использовать для отправки сообщений между разными странами? Имеет ли значение выбор учетной записи если нужно отправить сообщение из другой страны?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не понятен, вы хотите создать свой почтовый сервер, поддерживающий передачу писем по протоколу SMTP?

Comment: Да имеено  так.  И пользоваться им будут не только в России вот и интересует нормальнло ли работает отправка из разных стран.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для того, чтобы ваша реализация smtp-клиента/-сервера была способна взаимодействовать с другими реализациями smtp-серверов, она должна отвечать требованиям соответствующих [rfc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFC).

в rfc5321 (включающем последние на данный момент поправки и дополнения к протоколу [smtp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP)) в [секции 1.1.  Transport of Electronic Mail](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-1.1) о транспортировке сообщений говорится следующее:

> SMTP is independent of the particular transmission subsystem and requires only a reliable ordered data stream channel. While this document specifically discusses transport over TCP, other transports are possible.

мой вольный перевод:

> smtp не зависит от какой-то конкретной передающей подсистемы и требует лишь надёжного канала передачи упорядоченных данных. хотя в данном документе обсуждается траспорт поверх tcp, другие транспорты тоже возможны.

и далее в [секции 4.5.4.2.  Receiving Strategy](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.4.2) уточняется по поводу порта:

> The SMTP server SHOULD attempt to keep a pending listen on the SMTP port (specified by IANA as port 25) at all times.

мой вольный перевод:

> smtp-серверу следует пытаться слушать smtp-порт (определённый iana как порт 25) всё время.

действительно, на сайте [iana](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANA) в списке [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) сказано, что для протокола smtp зарезервированы порты 25/tcp и 25/udp.

---

#### вывод:

для связи с smtp-серверами, реализации которых соответствуют rfc5321, следует использовать:

- протокол: **tcp**
- порт: **25**

Comment: Если порт для клиента устанавливается так - `smtpServer.Port = 25;` то как установить `протокол: tcp` ?

Comment: tcp — протокол [транспортного уровня](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI). протокол ssl находится где-то между прикладным и транспортным уровнем, но точно выше последнего — он работает поверх протоколов этого уровня (того же tcp). т.е., «альтернативой» он быть не может. «альтернативой» может быть другой протокол трансп. уровня. например, udp. если в настройках нет выбора протокола трансп. уровня, значит умолчанием с огромной вероятностью служит именно tcp.

Comment: Класс `SmtpClient ` в с# не предоставляет таких настроек  насколько мне известно.

Comment: значит, не забивайте этим голову. если бы там использовался не tcp, а, например, udp, то общение со всеми популярными реализациями smtp-серверов было бы просто невозможным.