# Как в exim4 изменить исходящий порт SMTP?

Tags: linux, debian, exim4

Хостер блокирует исходящие соединения на 25, 465 и 587 порты:

> Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

Comment: 1. вы точно уверены, что блокируется именно **исходящий** порт? (проверка: `$ telnet mx.yandex.ru 25` — исходящий порт будет выбран программой *telnet* случайно). 2. если хостер блокирует спамерскую активность, то **обязательно** предоставляет свой сервер в качестве *smarthost*-а.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

Comment: 1. «on ports» — «**на** порты», а не «**с** портов». 2. там же приведены ссылки на использование smarthost-ов (так в терминологии exim-а называются почтовые ретрансляторы, «релеи», relays).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо. Т.е. без смартхоста отправить почту не получится никак?

Comment: разве что на свой собственый smarthost (relay) «во внешнем мире», который будет слушать какой-нибудь нестандартный порт и уже нормально отсылать почту.

Comment: давайте аналогию приведу. надеюсь, она будет понятнее: вашему компьютеру запретили соединения во внешний мир на порты 80 и 443. вы сможете после этого «сёрфить» по веб-сайтам без использования проксирования (читай ретрансляции)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да, теперь понятно. По-моему они специально запутывают: "you can set up your own email server on an instance using a non-standard port".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что, собственно, делает *smtp*-сервер, когда ему надо передать сообщение (т.н. «электронное письмо»)?

(я немного упрощаю, чтобы не превращать ответ в простыню):

1. из адреса получателя берётся доменное имя (ну, например, из `user@ya.ru` берётся `ya.ru.`)
2. совершается *dns*-запрос для получения *mx*-записи, соответствующей данному имени. что-то типа:

   ```
   $ dig +short -t mx ya.ru
   10 mx.yandex.ru.
   ```
3. затем запрашиваются ip-адреса серверов, в которые резолвится полученное имя (`mx.yandex.ru.`)
4. затем (для передачи сообщения) к ip-адресам из полученного списка производятся попытки подключиться по протоколу smtp на [**закреплённый за этим протоколом порт номер 25**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663552/178576)
5. если ни с одним из серверов не удалось соединиться, получаем ситуацию: соообщение не отправлено

поэтому «менять исходящий 25-й порт» не имеет смысла: smtp-серверы по всему миру слушают входящие соединения именно на этом порту.

---

вам стоит последовать совету из приведённой вами [ссылки](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/): воспользоваться *smarthost*-ом (так в терминологии *exim*-а называется почтовый ретранслятор, *smtp relay*). либо одним из там упомянутых (или неупомянутых, благо их есть в интернетах), либо собственным.